# Problem getting wp posts in plugin with wp_remote_get

Tags: wp-remote-get

I am creating a plugin to send posts to an external program. But I get a problem by getting the posts.

I created the code below to get the posts and echo them. But if I run it, it goes to the empty error message. When I echo the response. It only gets 'Array'

If I just post `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` in a browser, I get a JSON with my posts

What am I doing wrong?

```
$remoteargs = array(
        'timeout'     => 20,
        'redirection' => 5,
        'httpversion' => '1.1',
        'blocking'    => false,
        'headers'     => array(),
        'cookies'     => array(),
        'sslverify'   => false,
    ); 

$response = wp_remote_get( 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', $remoteargs );
// Exit if error.
if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        echo $response->get_error_message();
            return;
    }
// Get the body.
$posts = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
// Exit if nothing is returned.
if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
        echo 'emptyerror';
        return;
    }
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        echo $post;
}**
```

Comment: If you're getting `Array` how are you echoing the response? Do you meant he `$response` variable? There are two stray asterix at the end of your code, I also see `echo $post` which won't work as that variable won't be a string if the request is succesful. Can you indent your code correctly?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I had some problems with posting it here so te asterisks are not in my code. I tried to echo the response variable as you said. But then I get "Array" as a result. But as I understand I have to format it in another type to show it?

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes on my code

```
        $remoteargs = array(
            'timeout' => 20,
            'redirection' => 5,
            'httpversion' => '1.1',
            'blocking' => false,
            'headers' => array(),
            'cookies' => array(),
            'body' => array(),
            'sslverify' => false,
        );

        $response = wp_remote_get( 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',$remoteargs);

        // Exit if error.
        if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
            echo $response->get_error_message();
            return;
        }

        // Get the body.
        $posts = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );

        // Exit if nothing is returned.
        if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
            var_dump($response);
            return;
        }
```

It delivers me an empty array like this

array(5) { ["headers"]=> array(0) { } ["body"]=> string(0) "" ["response"]=> array(2) { ["code"]=> bool(false) ["message"]=> bool(false) } ["cookies"]=> array(0) { } ["http_response"]=> NULL }

If I try http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts in a browser of Postmen, it I get the posts. So what is missing in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Remove or change

```
 'blocking' => false,
```

to true as you are not making any Ajax call